# 3D pdf plot within latex without any external sources

Tags: plot, 3d, tikz-3dplot

I have searched a lot but found nothing on this topic. Most of the references talk about importing mesh data from matlab or similar software into a processor which then generates `.u3d` file that can be imported into `LaTeX`. Hence, there is no MWE with my question.

The question is that if a `3d` surface is being generated from a function using surf in `LaTeX`, it already knows the mesh, size and other details. Is there a way to convert that plot into `u3d` format on the fly within latex and then import it into resulting pdf document? At the most, I would be glad with mesh data being generated from latex and then some tool may be used to convert it into `u3d` file for subsequent inclusion into the main document.

Comment: See pgfplots manual starting on page 136 (Surface Plots).

Comment: What's the point if you are just going to reinclude it anyway? If you are already generating it, what purpose does the detour serve?

Comment: @cfr: They are useful for demonstration purposes in thesis / presentations etc. Not all 3D graphics are uniform in all directions

Comment: Note that I have no idea what a `u3d` file is ...